# Error while trying to start gulp process

Tags: gulp, node-sass

After not working a while on a project I got the following error when trying to start the process:

```
$ gulp
LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
      throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
      ^

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (57)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1
    at module.exports (LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (LOCAL_PATH/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:187:21)
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to sort this out. So any hint is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1 (as said in the error message), you can see the compatibility table for macOS:

`OS X | x64 | 0.10, 0.12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

You are probably using Node 8?

The latest version of `node-sass` does support Node 8: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

Try running `npm install node-sass@latest` to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, v8.3.0.
What's the best solution? Downgrading to Node 7? Sorry, as you probably are recognizing, I'm a noob …

Comment: I added to my answer. Try running `npm install node-sass@latest` to upgrade to a newer `node-sass` version.